# Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. 2022 problem

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

I know that a similar question has already been asked here, but it's already about 5 years old... So the information from there couldn't help me and I decided to create a new topic on this problem for 2022 yr.

- configuration.module.rules[3] should be one of these:
  ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, ru
  les?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
  -> A rule.
  Details:

  - configuration.module.rules[3].loader should be a non-empty string.
    -> A loader request.

My Webpack.Config:

```
const path = require('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/index.jsx"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].[hash].js"
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: "./src/index.html"}),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(css|less)$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)/,
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets:["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactreduxapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "frankfmy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "less-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I was able to figure it out myself
And here is the solution to this problem:

```
{
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                rules: [{
                    use: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                rules: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets:["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }]
            }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).